# Millimeter Graph Curve Type Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, applied-physics

I have question regarding graphing on a millimeter graph, with which I'm sure most of you are familiar and I apologize for it's simplicity.

For example, if I graph the period squared over the length of a mathematical pendulum (i.e. $\frac {T^{2}}{l}$), I have to plot it as a straight line, even though the relationship is exponential. But when I plot acceleration over total mass on a hanging block for example, (that is, $a = \frac {m_{1}g}{m_{1} + m_{2}}$) I have to take into account that the relationship is a $y = x^{-1}$ curve. Can anyone clear this up for me, how to define the type of curve on different relationships?

P.s, another example to clear my question. What curve would I plot on a graph of range of projectile motion over angle of inclination (should it be linear since range and angle are linearly related)? Same question for maximum height of projectile motion over angle of inclination (should it be exponential since the relationship between max height and angle is exponential i.e. $h_{max} = ksin^{2}{\alpha}$, where $k = \frac {v_{initial}^{2}}{2g}$).

The question only applies for a millimeter graph!

Thank you in advance!

[image: A millimeter graph page]

Comment: A straight line is usually preferable when working by hand, because we can do visual regression quite accurately with a ruler. It's hard to gauge the curvature of $x^2$ or any other complicated curve visually. We can massage what axis items to plot in order to force a straight line graph, then read of a particular constant we want from the intercept or gradient of the line, etc.

Comment: If "millimeter graph" just means graph paper in increments of millimeters, then like any graphing you would define the horizontal variable X and vertical variable Y, and simply plot each pair of (X,Y) as a point, regardless of what the function Y=f(X) is.

Comment: @James thanks for the reply, so what would be the curve type on the last two questions I mentioned according to you? Straight or exponential?

Comment: @RC_23 thanks for the reply. Physics Lab graphs don't quite work like that. You plot the points and you draw the line (line being dependent on the type of equation you have) as close as possible to all the points plotted (since there is some error it won't be perfect obviously).

Comment: What is a "millimeter graph"? I have never heard the term used before.

Comment: @JohnRennie, this is the millimeter graph paper https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Graph_paper_mm_A4.pdf/page1-1200px-Graph_paper_mm_A4.pdf.jpg.

Comment: @Tommy OK I have voted to reopen your question, though it will take two more votes before the question is reopened. Though I don't see what the significance of the graph paper is. Whether the line is straight or curved doesn't depend on whether the graph paper is in millimeters, inches or indeed furlongs, just as long as the scales are linear not log scales or some other non-linear scale.

Comment: You can help yourself by cleaning up the last paragraph.  You ask what curve for height vs. inclination angle.  You say it's linear, but then you write down a function that is not linear.  Then you say it's exponential, but the function you present is a sine squared.   I can't see what you are getting at in the last paragraph.   Perhaps if we can understand your question in the last paragraph, we'll understand the entre question.

Comment: John Reenie thanks for the open, my following question to Gary will hopefully clear it up for you as well. @garyp I was trying to conclude by myself what type of curve it would be. Maybe it is a little mixed up and I apologize, but think of it in the following way. If I give you a set of data about the maximum height of a projectile motion and the angle of inclination which output those heights, and ask you to plot the graph of max height over the angle, what type of curve would you draw (taking into consideration that it is a lab graph) and why? Same for range and angle?

Comment: It seems like you have a data set, and want to find the best fit of a particular model to the data.  If that's correct, you need to look into curve fitting.  But beware: the physical situation that you have chosen does not lend itself well to simple curve fitting.  It's not the place to start to learn curve fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we know, or we think we know, that some physical property $y$ is related to another physical property $x$ by some function $f$:

$$ y = f(x) \tag{1} $$

To test this all we have to do is experimentally measure $x$ and $y$ then draw a graph with $f(x)$ on the $x$ axis and $y$ on the $y$ axis. If our equation is correct we would get a straight line with gradient $1$.

The reason we want a straight line is that it's easy to check if points lie on a straight line. Usually we can tell just by looking at the points, but if you want to get more sophisticated a simple linear regression will give you the gradient and the standard error in the gradient. So our straight line graph is a quick and easy way to tell if our equation (1) is correct.

The problem is that often our equation involves constants that we don't know. For example you mention the period of a pendulum where the equation for the period is:

$$ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac \ell g} $$

and we may not know $g$ so we can't just plot $f(\ell)$ on the $x$ axis. But usually we can rearrange our equation to separate out the unknown constants like $g$. In this case we can write the equation as:

$$ T = \left( \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{g}} \right) \sqrt{\ell} $$

Now everything inside the brackets is a constant, so if we graph $T$ on the $y$ axis and $\sqrt{\ell}$ on the $x$ axis we will get a straight line with a gradient $2\pi/\sqrt{g}$. The straight line gives us an easy check our equation is correct, and as a bonus we can get the value of $g$ from the gradient.

You ask about a system where $y = f(x^{-1})$ so let's take as an example the frequency $f$ of a standing wave on a string as a function of the length of the string $\ell$. The equation for the frequency of the fundamental mode is:

$$ f = \frac{\sqrt{T}}{2\ell\sqrt{\rho}} $$

where $T$ is the tension in the string and $\rho$ is the mass per unit length of the string. Again we may not know one of both of these so we can't simply graph $f$ on the $y$ axis and $\sqrt{T}/(2\ell\sqrt{\rho})$ on the $x$ axis. But again we can separate out the (unknown) constants to get:

$$ f = \left(\frac{\sqrt{T}}{2\sqrt{\rho}}\right) \frac1\ell$$

where again everything inside the brackets is a constant. And now we see that if we graph $f$ against $1/\ell$ we will get a straight line with a gradient $\sqrt{T}/(2\sqrt{\rho})$.

Finally you mention the height of a projectile where:

$$ h = \frac{v^2 \sin^2(\theta)}{2g} $$

where I guess you are taking $v$ to be constant and varying $\theta$. In this case we rewrite the equation as:

$$ h = \left(\frac{v^2}{2g}\right) \sin^2(\theta) $$

where once again everything inside the bracket is a constant. And we can can graph $f$ on the $y$ axis and $\sin^2(\theta)$ on the $x$ axis to get our straight line.

Now these are all fairly straightforward equations, and when the function we are investigating is more complicated it may be harder to rearrange our equation to get a straight line. However I hope this gives you the basic idea.

Comment: It is very well explained, thank you, but I'm struggling to understand a specific point. You mentioned that the period equation would output a straight line with the mentioned gradient, but why would it if the relationship is a square root? Shouldn't the curve take the form of the square root graph?